# Is there a southern British accent in which emphasis changes /ɪf/ to /ɪv/, /wɒz/ to /wɒs/?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, phonemes

Is there a southern British accent in which different emphasis changes /ɪf/ to /ɪv/ and /wɒz/ to /wɒs/?

I'm just thinking that I want to do this. So the following phrases:

- *what* was *that*?
- what *if*?

Comment: i'm wondering if i'm shouting / whispering words due to strong / weak stress.

Comment: Isn't this determined by context ([phonology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_rule)) rather than accent? How do you pronounce *if that was*?

Comment: not sure. i'm currently think maybe i pronounce it that way when rapidly speaking, due to [assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)) @reinierpost

Answer (score 1):

*Partial answer.*
The voicing of fricatives in function words is known to vary somewhat between different times and places. Hence the voicing in present-day English of the formerly unvoiced "f" in *of,* and the variation between /ð/ and /θ/ in *with.*

I have no idea how common it is, but I have actually come across a reference to pronouncing *if* with voiced /v/ in an article "Some Notes on Pronunciation", published in *[The Irish Monthly](https://books.google.com/books?id=2WY5AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=The%20Irish%20Monthly%20%22Some%20notes%20on%20pronunciation%22&source=bl&ots=23OuAhkRpR&sig=QV_LtiYf2lW6t-DMkZBVX1pumDo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6vKKE64XaAhWq6oMKHVfCDu8Q6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=the%20conjunction%20if%20is%20sometimes%20vulgarly%20pronounced%20iv&f=false),* Vol. 23, No. 261 (Mar., 1895), pp. 145-156, which consists of excerpts from a lecture on pronunciation by the English professor George R. Kingdon (the lecture seems to be full of peeves about pronunciations that Kingdon did not like).

> The conjunction *if* is sometimes vulgarly pronounced *iv.*

(p. 153)

So I think we can at least say that you are not the only speaker who has ever felt that *if* might be pronounced with /v/. However, I don't anything about the distribution or frequency of this pronunciation, or whether it would be affected by emphasis.

Unfortunately, I also don't know anything about the use of /s/ in *was.*